# Inserting items into sqlite db, size remains the same

Tags: python, sqlite

Something weird is going on with a py script that inserts/updates into a sql database of mine.

I let it run for a few iterations, then to double check that it has done its job, I open my database with SQLite Database Browser to see if it has added any entries. Here's what's weird:

- 15015 items BEFORE insertion.
- After insertion, entry #15015 has changed to the inserted one.
- Entry #15014 has changed to the previous entry #15015.
- Entry #1 didn't get bumped out in any way.

So what the hell is going on here? Is it something with my sql GUI? Is it a max db size thing? Why did it work perfectly up to item #15015? Did anything get overwritten and how do I get it insert new entries at #15016 instead?? Here's the insert code

```
con2 = lite.connect('games.db')
with con2:

    cur2 = con2.cursor()
    cur2.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Games (Id) VALUES ('" + mdict['Id'] + "')")
    for key in mdict:
        cur2.execute("UPDATE Games SET '" + key + "' = '" + mdict[key].encode('utf-8') + "' WHERE Id = '" + mdict['Id'].encode('utf-8') + "'" )
    con2.commit()
```

Comment: Obviously there is only update happening. Can you show us example about #15014, #15015 and the item you want to insert? It's hard to tell what's happening without concrete examples.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is elsewhere? What else runs? I have millions of rows in some sqlite databases.

Comment: `SQLite` was originally designed with a policy of avoiding arbitrary limits! so the problem is because of your querying !!! can you show the rest of your code ? http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Apparently there were a bunch of duplicates that I thought I had safeguarded against, but hadn't... Problem solved.